# problems packaging kivy with conda

Tags: python, kivy, cython, anaconda

I cannot use kivy in conda because Cython is missing but I am sure that it is installed.

My build.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
make
python setup.py install
```

My meta.yaml:

```
package:
  name: kivy
  version: 1.9

source:
   git_url: https://github.com/kivy/kivy  

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
    - cython

about:
  home: http://kivy.org
  summary: "latest development version of kivy"`
```

I do get the error:
    ImportError: No module named 'Cython'

Any ideas why that happens ?

Comment: I don't know how conda works or what exactly the config file does, but cython is required to build kivy, not to run it (whereas you have it the other way around in the requirements section).

Comment: yep. that solved it. At least the cython issue